# Getting 406 Could not find acceptable representation /Spring JSON Test. How to ignore .htm extension in tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, content-negotiation

Controller needs uses .htm extensions for all handlers, including JSON REST endpoints. How should I test for REST endpoints?

**Problem:**
I cannot disable suffix interpretation and I am getting 406 "Could not find acceptable representation"

**Tried attempts:**
I reviewed posts on stackoverflow related to 406, but could not find relevant one to the case where 'htm' suffix is used in tests. When you remove '.htm' suffix from both Controller and Test - the test is passing.

Here is controller with /changePassword.htm endpoint:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    public static class ResultBean {

        private final String result;

        public String getResult() {
            return result;
        }


        public ResultBean(String result) {
            this.result = result;
        }
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value="/changePassword.htm", method= RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json" }) 
    public @ResponseBody ResultBean changePassword (
            @RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {

        return new ResultBean("OK");
    }
}
```

And here is the test with configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { HomeControllerTest.Config.class })
public class HomeControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MainController controller = new MainController();

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public static class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

          @Override
          public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.favorPathExtension(false)
                    .favorParameter(true)
                    .parameterName("mediaType")
                    .ignoreUnknownPathExtensions(true)
                    .ignoreAcceptHeader(false)
                    .useJaf(false)
                    .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
          }

          @Override
          public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
              configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
          }       
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldPassChangePasswordBean() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(post("/changePassword.htm")
                .accept("*/*")
                .param("username", "example")
                .param("password", "abcdef")                
                )
            .andExpect(status().isOk()); // Test produces 406 instead of 200
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

On newer version of Spring (4+ I think), mime type is determined from suffix first.

So If you use a `.htm` suffix, Spring will default to produce HTML even if you don't want to.

One way to bypass this is to use a filter that rewrite URL.  For instance [tuckey URL rewriter filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)

With this, you can set some rules like:

`/my/page/that/return/json.htm` is rewriten to `/my/page/that/return/json` so that Spring can produce data according to the `Accept` header.

Answer (score 0):

with Spring 5,   try changing your URL of your web service to .json!  that is the right fix.  great details here http://stick2code.blogspot.com/2014/03/solved-orgspringframeworkwebhttpmediaty.html